# VBA Dateadd Format - Need In Total Minutes

Tags: vba, formatting

I have a userform in Microsoft Excel that I want to use as a stopwatch. However the format of "hh:mm" does not allow it to go above 23:59 as it goes back to 00:00

```
Private Sub SpinButton2_SpinUp()

If InsertEvent.TextBox1 = vbNullString Then
InsertEvent.TextBox1 = "00:00"

Else

InsertEvent.TextBox1.Value = Format(DateAdd("n", 1,       InsertEvent.TextBox1.Value), "hh:mm")
'InsertEvent.TextBox1.Value = TimeValue("mm:ss")
'InsertEvent.TextBox1.Value = Format(InsertEvent.TextBox1.Value, "hh:mm")

End If

End Sub
```

Is there anyway to format this so that it can work as a clock of total minutes? Ideally I need it to go to about 125 minutes or so (125:00) but it doesn't matter if it is unlimited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the built in Date/Time functions for this as you want a representation that is not a Date/Time.

Assuming you want to read the spinner value into the textbox:

```
Private Sub SpinButton2_SpinUp()
    Dim minutes As Integer: minutes = Val(InsertEvent.SpinButton2.Value)
    Dim hh As Integer:      hh = minutes \ 60
    Dim mm As Integer:      mm = minutes - (hh * 60)

    InsertEvent.TextBox1.Text = Format$(hh, "00") & ":" & Format$(mm, "00")
End Sub
```

To use a manually entered value from the textbox as the starting up/down point you need to re-parse "hh:mm" back to minutes, for example in the textbox Exit event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If (IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text)) Then
        '// entering a number only assumes its minutes
        SpinButton2.Value = TextBox1.Text
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim hhmm() As String: hhmm = Split(TextBox1.Text, ":")
    If (UBound(hhmm) = 1) Then
        If (IsNumeric(hhmm(0)) And IsNumeric(hhmm(1))) Then
            SpinButton2.Value = (hhmm(0) * 60) + hhmm(1)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    SpinButton2.Value = 0
End Sub
```

(Should add error checking for overflow/exceeding the spinners .Max property)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's almost what I need, however if I enter a number into the text box and want to increase/decrease using the spin button it doesn't work. It worked with my original dateadd... 

For instance if I type 20:00 into the clock to start with, and then click on the "spin up" button it starts straight from 00:00...

Comment: The ability to do that trivially is lost, updated above.